# How to replace occurence of substring with another string containing index of occurence?

Tags: bash

I need to do what's described below, in bash script.

Let's say I have a file containing text:

```
Some text foo
Some text foo, another text foo
```

I want to replace `foo` with another string but ended with the index of `foo` in the line

So I want the output to be:

```
Some text bar1
Some text bar1, another text bar2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do that:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; sub(/foo/, "bar" i); i++) ; } 1' file
```

Note that `foo` is interpreted as a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `perl` one-liner:

```sh
$ perl -pe 'my $i = 1; s/foo/"bar" . $i++/eg' input.txt
Some text bar1
Some text bar1, another text bar2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk variant:

```sh
awk '{for(i=0; sub(/foo/, "bar" ++i););} 1' file

Some text bar1
Some text bar1, another text bar2
```